# No syntax highlighting in eclipse for java

Tags: java, eclipse, editor

There is no syntax highlighting in java files in my eclipse..This happened all of a sudden..Not sure why..

This is how it is looking now..

[image]

As mentioned in other posts..i tried to change the color from preferences window and there is nothing when i type java..something really messed up...

[image]

AAny suggestions..

Update:

It seems Java plugin is not installed..as per the below screeenshot

[image]

And when i try to install java plugin it says new version is already installed as per the below screenshot

[image]

Comment: DId you remove java via the p2 plugin manager?

Comment: @hexafraction Not sure..I don't remember any thing like that..but how can i verify?

Comment: Check the help menu's software installation/uninstallatin options and make sure Java is still installed.

Comment: @hexafraction java plugin is not installed but when i try to install it says latest version already installed..Updated the original question with screenshots

Comment: Did you change which JRE you use to launch Eclipse?

Comment: Here is my eclipse.ini file http://pastebin.com/grLcCxA1

Comment: That doesn't really indicate which one's being used.  Is this a package from your Linux distribution?  Did that get changed?  Have you tried a Kepler package from download.eclipse.org?

Comment: for those who have "Eclipse IDE for PHP Developers" without Java syntax highlighting

Answer (score 2):

Closing the file's tab and re-opening it fixed it for me.

(I actually closed all the tabs...)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue all of a sudden after a commit/update project operation.

The point is, default editor of Eclipse has changed somehow and we have to set it back to normal.

Try the below method,
1. Goto *Windows* -> Click *Preferences*
2. From the Preferences window goto *General* -> *Editors* -> Click *File Associations*
3. You can choose the default editor for *.java files here

[image: Preferences Window]

When I first opened *Preferences*, *'Text editor'* was set as the default editor for .java files and then I changed it back to *'Java Editor'*.

Now it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a corrupt installation or you have recently installed a corrupt plugin.

The following steps might help.

In your Install window,

1. view your "already installed" plugins.
2. select the "Installation History" tab.
3. select a previous stable configuration
4. Click the "Revert" button

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; open another workspace, then come back to the original workspace.

Ok this is odd, but for me, all the highlighting suddenly went away for Java files. I explored all of these ideas here, with no effect. I created a new workspace, planning to move everything to it. I realized that can be a pain to move many projects over, so I went back into the original workspace to look at some settings, and poof - the highlighting was working again.

Answer (score 0):

I have one java class file like a text editor.

I tried following,

1. Select the respective java class file from eclipse.
2. Right click on the file and mouse hover on "Open with".
3. Select java editor.

Now its works.