# Why is syntax highlighting enabled in some header files and not others?

Tags: eclipse, rational-team-concert

What setting causes Eclipse/RTC to provide syntax highlighting for a given file?

Using IBM's RTC, considering two .hpp files in the same directory, one has syntax highlighting and the other is black and white text.  I can copy the contents of the "good" header file to the other and the "bad" file is still black and white.

Comment: Eclipse remembers with which editor the file was last opened. Maybe in case of the black and white, this was with the text editor. Right-click the file and choose _Open With > Default Editor_.

Comment: Tried that with no change.

Comment: You specifically want to choose your C/C++ Editor, not anything called default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the file [text file encoding](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2FwrkAdv_encoding.htm) for both files (`Edit > Encoding` menu of an editor)

A difference of encoding might throw off Eclipse.

Make sure both files are opened with the same kind of editor view (like [here for Java files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43489462/6309)).

Comment: Both are the same encoding, but that may have revealed more hints.  The Source menu for the "good" file has many options available that the "bad" file does not.  Trying to compare other differences has not lead to much, yet...